# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'Click'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

i'm trying to automate a login process on moodle but when i try to find and send keys in the username feild is thsows me error
here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\Install\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://lms.jspmrscoe.edu.in/?redirect=0")
username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'username').is_displayed()
username.Click()
username.send_keys("name*emphasized text*")
```

the code works fine till the finding of the element but when i try to click on it by .click() it shows a error is like this:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'Click'
```

Comment: `.is_displayed()` returns a boolean of True or False depending on whether that element is displayed. You need to check `if` that element `isdisplayed` but then you have to `.Click()` the _element itself_, not the result of `isdisplayed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```py
username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'username').is_displayed()
```

the `is_displayed()` function is called.

This returns `True` or `False` - a boolean.

You cannot call the `.Click()` function on `username` since booleans don't have that function

Comment: yes this worked and also cleared misconception in my mind , thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Click on a Boolean, here is the solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\Install\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://lms.jspmrscoe.edu.in/?redirect=0")
username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')

#in case you want to click when username is diplayed
# do this
if username.is_displayed():
  username.Click()
  username.send_keys("name*emphasized text*")
```